# Evaluating $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate
>
> $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}}$$

This question was asked in my high school exam, we haven't discussed the solutions yet. I tried substituting $x=\tan^3(\alpha)$ so that I can get $\sqrt {\tan(\alpha) \sec^2(\alpha)}$ in the denominator and then I tried using By-parts but I was still getting an integral which I was not able to solve, kindly don't post the whole solution, just a hint would be sufficient.

Update: Some of my classmates are saying that it should be $\sqrt{x}$ instead of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ in the denominator and solving that is easy, but still I am curious about this integral.

Comment: You would have a lot of trouble since you face elliptic integrals. Are you sure about the cube root ?

Comment: Maybe it was multiplication between $x$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$ rather than addition?

Comment: More likely this integral: $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt x + \root3\of x}.$$ This used to be a standard rationalizing substitution exercise.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici are the elliptic integrals same as hypergeometric function which David mentioned in his answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the problem is correct, let $x=t^3$
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{ \sqrt{x + \sqrt[3]{x}}}=3\int \frac{ t^2}{\sqrt{t^3+t}}\,dt$$
$$I=2 \left(\sqrt{t^3+t}-\sqrt[4]{i^2} F\left(\left.i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{i^2}}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$$

We can also simplify @David G. Stork's first result as
$$I=2 \sqrt{x+\sqrt[3]{x}} \,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},1;\frac{1}{4};-\frac{1}{x^{2/3}}\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you've copied the problem incorrectly.  Anyway, according to *Mathematica*:

$$\int \frac{dx}{ \sqrt{x + \sqrt[3]{x}}}= \frac{2 \sqrt{x+\sqrt[3]{x}} \left(\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{5}{4};-\frac{1}{x^{2/3}}\right)+x^{2/3}\right)}{x^{2/3}
   }$$

where $F$ is the Hypergeometric function, and

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{x}} = 2 \sqrt{x}-3 \sqrt[3]{x}+6 \sqrt[6]{x}-6 \log \left(\sqrt[6]{x}+1\right)$$